# Normal force with applied force below the horizontal

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

The normal force for the case of pushing a crate across a floor with an applied force $F_{app}$ at an angle $\theta$ above the horizontal is given by Newton's second law:

$$ \sigma F_y = 0 = n - mg + F_{app}\sin(\theta) $$

Thus:

$$ n = mg - F_{app}\sin(\theta) $$

If the angle of $F_{app}$ is below the horizontal, we get:

$$ \sigma F_y = 0 = n - mg - F_{app}\sin(\theta) $$

Thus:

$$ n = mg + F_{app}\sin(\theta) $$

If the second derivation is wrong, I want to know precisely why. I say it is correct. If correct, why can't I use angles measured from the $+x$ axis to solve problems for angles below the horizontal?  Example, if the angle is $20$ degrees below the horizontal, $\theta$ is $+340$ or $-20$ when measured from the $+x$ axis.  This gives:

$$ n = mg - 0.342~F_{app} $$

This is wrong because of the sign of the second term.  Obviously, the normal force increases for $F_{app}$ at an angle below the horizontal.

Comment: To avoid confusion, you need to clarify the angle. The normal force will be reduced if the applied force has a vertical upward  component and increased if the applied force has a downward vertical component.

Comment: I attempted to clarify.  I want to define all angles from the +x axis, as is often done.  The problem is that when this is done after using Newton's 2nd Law (as shown in my original post) I get the wrong sign. As I see it, we should be able to use Newton's 2nd law in both cases and derive TWO different equations.  Do you see an error in either of my derivations for n?

Comment: It’s still not clear. A picture is worth a thousand words. Show the crate and the force and the angle the force makes with the horizontal

Comment: I will If I can find out how to upload a pic.

Comment: Just click on the add a picture icon and drag and drop  your JPEG file

Answer (score 0):

You have got your signs wrong. If $F$ is applied at an angle above the horizontal then it increases the normal force, and vice versa.

So if the angle $\theta$ is positive when *above* the horizontal then the normal force $N$ is

$N = mg + F_{app}\sin \theta$

If the angle $\theta$ is negative i.e. below the horizontal then you can still use this formula, remembering that $\sin \theta$ is negative if $\theta$ is in the range $(-180^0,0^0)$. Or you can replace $\theta$ with $\theta’=-\theta$ which is positive when below the horizontal, in which case

$N = mg - F_{app}\sin \theta’$

Remember that the normal force cannot become negative, so strictly speaking the correct expression is

$N = \max(mg + F_{app}\sin \theta,0)$

Comment: I appreciate your response.  However, I can't agree with your very first statement.  A vector that is applied above the horizontal points into the first quadrant.  A vector that is applied below the horizontal points into the 4th quadrant.  Thus, for a force applied below the horizontal, the normal force increases.  An angle of +340 wrt the + x-axis increases the normal force.  If we can't agree on that, we can never agree on signs.

Comment: @Joe This is the root cause of your confusion. A force applied from a direction *below* the horizontal has an *upwards* vertical component and so it will *reduce* the normal force. A force applied from a direction *above* the horizontal has a *downwards* vertical component and so it will *increase* the normal force.

Comment: Thanks again.  I agree 100% with what you just wrote.  I fully understand that.  You and I do not agree on what below or above the horizontal means.  Serway and Vuille (11th Ed.) believe (as do I) that a force applied BELOW the horizontal points into the FOURTH quadrant.  If I understand your statement, you say the opposite.

Comment: @Joe You need to think in terms of the direction *from which* the force is applied, which is opposite to the direction in which the force vector points. The force is *pushing* the crate, not pulling it.

Comment: If you can put that issue aside, do you agree that there are TWO derivations possible from Newton's second law?  One for pushing one for pulling?  (What one means by above or below is not my question.)  Do my TWO equations for n look correct?

Comment: @Joe If the force is pulling towards a direction at an angle $\theta$ above the horizontal then $N = mg - F_{app} \sin \theta$. If the force is pushing from a direction at an angle $\theta$ above the horizontal then $N = mg + F_{app} \sin \theta$.

Comment: Great!  We agree on the two different equations that result from using Newton's 2nd Law and free-body diagrams.  (Those appear in my original post.)  Thus, we return to your original idea of using a theta prime.  It seems that this is akin to the situation found with the use of the inverse tan function, defined only for the first and fourth quadrants.  Or...the natural log function, where we must define the domain as x > 0.  Here, I could live with this (I think) if we set theta equal to -theta with theta between 180 and 360 degrees.  I've NEVER seen a textbook attempt this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for a normal n = mg – Fsin(θ) is all you need, assuming F is an external force, acting at an angle θ up from the the horizontal, on mass m which on a horizontal surface.  In this case n is decreased by the action of F.  If θ is negative, the sin(θ) goes negative and n is increased.